# gcc narrowing conversion in + operator

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to compile some fairly simple C++ code with GCC 6, but getting a narrowing conversion warning.  This is problematic because we treat warnings as errors.

```
struct S {
    short int a;
    short int b;
};

short int getFoo();
short int getBar();

std::array<S, 2> arr = {{
    {5, getFoo()},
    {3, getFoo() + getBar()}   // Narrowing conversion here?
}};
```

You can see this code in action at https://godbolt.org/g/wHNxoc.  GCC says getFoo() + getBar() is narrowing from an int down to a short int.  What is causing the upcast to an int?  Is there any good solution here short of a forced cast to short int?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is due to the [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to
>   prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular,
>   **arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as
>   arguments**, and integral promotions are automatically applied after
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always
>   preserves the value.

As a consequence, `getFoo() + getBar()` has a type of *int*, which leads to the aforementioned warning.

To suppress a warning, you might make use of *static_cast*:

```
static_cast<short>(getFoo() + getBar())
```